# Singleton class with session timespan (for each browsing client) .NET CORE

Tags: c#, .net-core, ems

I'm trying to create singleton class but only for session.
So I want to have one instance for each user that enters website (it's for JMS server). Therefore - when session will be closed I have to invoke close connection from library.

So:

1. how to create class that will be one for each session?
2. how to catch event that session is not inactive and invoke some method?

Tried with `AddSingleton/AddTransient/AddScoped` but probably it's not proper way for the job (or I'm using it wrong).

To explain more - "Business Case" is web application, where user can check messages on queues on JMS server. User enters connection parameters on welcome page (login) - so when somebody uses app (and is connected to some JMS server), another User can enter page - see login and this another user creates his own connection to another JMS server.

Comment: As i understand, Scoped is what you are looking for. Singleton is initialized once and becomes used lifetime. Scoped is, injection happens for the request, and till the request finishes created objects being used again. Transient is the one that creates new object for everything. Even if its in the same request.

Comment: Hmm... I've generated Interface, and in startup changed to: services.AddScoped<IEMSConnectionService,EMSConnectionService>(); used dependency injection but I've got null for some reason... :/

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you want them per session, you might consider creating instances on session creation using:

```
_myClass = serviceProvider
          .GetRequiredService<IMyInterface>();
```

Comment: but where I have to do that? I'm using Razor Pages - so I use DI on Page Model side... on Login page?